# c++ error " expression must be a modifiable lvalue "

Tags: c++

I have a question for the code here , I am facing an error in this simple code with one struct , if you compile it then the compiler states in the error statement that  " expression must be a modifiable lvalue " .
What I basically want in this code is to assign for example a name with having an array of struct .
So when there gets written  x[1].identification = "Id";   , then the compiler gives the error .
I am quite stuck in this problem for some time .

Can anybody give a solution to this ?!

Thank you

---

Here is the code  :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
#include<windows.h>
//#include <ctime>
//#include <dos.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstdio>
#define max 20
using namespace std;


struct person
{

char identification[20];
long int code;
char group [20];
int experience;
int age;

};


int main() 
{

person x[10];

x[1].identification = "Id";  // this is where the error is being shown

system("cls");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: It try to assign an address of a const char pointer to constant address. `x[1].identification` is an array not a pointer so you can't put the address in it. if you must use a c string, use `strcpy` to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `const char*` to a `char` array. That makes no sense. Use `std::string` instead:

```
struct person {
    std::string identification;
    long int code;
    std::string group;
    int experience;
    int age;
};
```

You might also want to create a constructor, otherwise `code`, `experience` and `age` are undefined. You should probably require them at construction.

Comment: This does not solve the OP actual problem, even if it's a possible workaround...

Comment: @Rinzler How doesn't it solve OP's problem exactly?

Comment: The original error and problem is: `expression must be a modifiable lvalue` and not how to pass from a char array to an `std::string`

Comment: @Rinzler Using an `std::string` solves the problem. End of.

Comment: @juanchopanza Nice for you ;)

Comment: @Rinzler So, yeah, considering that he can't use an array there, are you saying that all solutions involving him not using a `char` array for `identifications` do "not solve OP's problem"? Because in that case I'm afraid there are none.